# Sobolev extension from a discrete set of points

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis

Let $1 > \alpha > 0$ and fix some $C > 0$. Consider $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a bounded domain and $Y \subset \Omega$ a discrete (finite) set of points. For $f: Y \to \mathbb{R}$ define
$$\|f\|_{C^\alpha(Y)} := \sup_{y \in Y} |f(y)| + \sup_{y\neq z \in Y} \frac{|f(y) - f(z)|}{|y - z|^\alpha}.$$
Is there an extension map $E: C^\alpha(Y) \to H^s(\Omega)$, where $s = n/2 + \alpha$, such that $Ef|_Y = f$, and there is a $C_1 = C_1(C, \Omega) > 0$ (independent of $Y$)
$$\|f\|_{C^\alpha(Y)} \leq C \implies \|Ef\|_{H^s(\Omega)} \leq C_1.$$
We require that $C_1$ is independent of $Y$; here $H^s$ denotes the Sobolev space of index $s$. In case of a negative answer, what is the optimal Sobolev exponent $s$ one can get on the right hand side (we always require the extension to be continuous so we may define the restriction)?

---

Some comments about the problem. Firstly, one can easily check that the extension defined as
$$Ef(x) := \min_{y \in Y} \Big(f(y) + |x - y|^\alpha \|f\|_{C^\alpha(Y)}\Big)$$
satisfies the required properties as a map $E: C^\alpha(Y) \to C^\alpha(\Omega) \subset H^{\alpha - \varepsilon}(\Omega)$, for any $\varepsilon > 0$. So the question has positive answer for $s = \alpha - \varepsilon$.

Also, by Sobolev embedding theorems, we know that $H^{n/2 + \alpha} (\Omega) \subset C^\alpha(\Omega)$. So we expect there should be a better Sobolev exponent for some other choice of extension.

Finally, if the answer to my question is negative, it would be interesting to consider the extension map $E$ into spaces $H^s(\Omega)$, where $s \geq 1$ (say for $n \geq 2$). If $s = 1$ one could expect a ``harmonic extension"  to be optimal; also, in this case if one takes a piecewise-linear extension on the triangulation determined by points in $Y$, I believe the answer is positive if $\alpha \geq \frac{1}{2}$. However this is not satisfactory, as in the application I have in mind $\alpha$ is very small.

References to literature are very welcome!

Comment: There is a series of articles of Fefferman in the Anals of Math. about such problems.

Comment: Thanks. It's indeed relevant, although I haven't been able to extract useful information yet. There are related papers by P. Shvartsman on Whitney-Sobolev extensions; e.g. ``Whitney-type extension theorems for jets generated by Sobolev functions". Unfortunately, these do not consider extension in L^2-based Sobolev spaces.

Comment: For $E \subset \mathbb R^n$ finite, $0 < s < 1$ and $sp > n$, let $\|f\|_{L^{s,p}(E)}$ be the trace norm $ \|f\|_{L^{s,p}(E)} = \inf\{\|F\|_{L^{s,p}(\mathbb R^n)} : F|_E = f\} $. Here $\| \cdot \|_{L^{s,p}(\mathbb R^n)}$ is the homogeneous fractional $L^{s,p}$ seminorm. I know a proof that the standard Whitney extension operator is bounded from $L^{s,p}(E)$ to $L^{s,p}(\mathbb R^n)$ following along the lines of Shvartsman's work, but it's a little long. Would you be interested in this?